# display console output on webpage

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, output

Please read the question before marking as duplicate. I have a list, I know how to use variable values using jstl core tag, but what I can't do is how to display the list elements in my webpage. I have tried everything so far and I have already included what I have tried(the question it has been marked duplicate for doesn't have the answer I need as I have already tried that).

I have this list in my method:

```
for (Instance i : instances) {
                ret.add(i);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(reservation.getInstances());
                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int o = 0; o < array.length(); o++) {
                    JSONObject obj = null;
                    try {
                        obj = array.getJSONObject(o);
                        obj.getString("instanceId");
                        obj.getString("state");
                        obj3 = list1.add(obj.getString("instanceId"));
                        obj4 = list1.add(obj.getString("state"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                    list1.get(j);

                    result = list1.get(j).toString();
                    System.out.println(result);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list1);
    return list1;

    }
```

In result, i am adding only the instance state and instance id. In my console, the output is correct(i.e. how I want it to be displayed, but when i try things like :

```
   out.println(DisplayInstance.result);
```

but in webpage it is not giving the content that I want to display

OR this

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("obj3", DisplayInstance.obj3);
request.getSession().setAttribute("obj4", DisplayInstance.obj4);
```

where i was adding the instance id and state to these objects, 
 and this on jsp

```
    Output Id:
    <c:out value="${sessionScope.obj3}"></c:out>
    Output State:
    <c:out value="${sessionScope.obj4}"></c:out>
```

and still i am not getting output on console. What else can i do?

Comment: out.println(DisplayInstance.result);  it gives you correct output ?

Comment: no it doesn't , only sysout(result); in my method gives the correct output on console

Comment: i-1bed6a34
{"name":"stopped","code":80}
i-5beb6ce1
{"name":"running","code":16} i get this in my console but i want this in my webpage also

Comment: on webpage, you want to display all object's instanceId and state, right ?

Comment: @vishalgajera yes that exactly what i want to do!

Comment: I have resolved it. I was returning ret instead of list1. Thanks

Comment: @vishalgajera I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was adding the JSON objects in the list list1 but I was returning list ret. All I had to do was change the return statement from return ret to return list1 and add this in my servlet:

```
List<String> inst=null;
try {
            DisplayInstance.authentication(accessKey, secretKey);
            inst = DisplayInstance.describeAllInstances(); 
     } catch (Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(inst);
```

and it works fine now.